# Why is answer NaN?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have five positive integers, I want to find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. index of array is number, but when I print answer, it's `NaN`

```js
var sumArr = []
var sum = 0
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        
        sumArr.push(arr.filter(item => item !== arr[i]).reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue, sum))
    }

    console.log(Math.min(sumArr), Math.max(sumArr))
}

let sides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];


const result = miniMaxSum(sides);
```

Comment: Consider using a debugger to step through the code line by line?

Comment: Math.min and Math.max do not take an array as an argument

Comment: Keep in mind that if your array contains duplicates, the filter will remove all of them, so the sum will not be the one you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're passing an array, those functions are expecting numbers instead. Take a look at [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

You can spread those arrays as follows:

```js
var sumArr = []
var sum = 0
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        
        sumArr.push(arr.filter(item => item !== arr[i]).reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue, sum))
    }

    console.log(Math.min(...sumArr), Math.max(...sumArr))
}

let sides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];


const result = miniMaxSum(sides);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand where the mistake was